# Returning an array pointer from a function in C/C++ without static integer

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I'm going to write a piece of code (Function) that returns a pointer to an array.
but I don't know how to do that.
The code I wrote is :

```
int* prime_factor(int temp){
int ctr;
int *ret;
int i = 0;
while (temp != 1){
    ctr = 2;
    if (temp%ctr != 0){
        ctr++;
    }
    else {
        *(ret + i) = ctr;
        temp /= ctr;
    }
}
return ret;
}
```

I guess that there's a need to such the thing :

```
else {
        ret = new int[1];
        *(ret +i) = ctr;
        temp /= ctr;
    }
```

But as you know , implementation of this stuff needs to be deleted the memory that you have allocated , so we have to delete the memory outside of the function , so it going to be nonstandard function. 
Indeed, i want to calculate the Prime factors of a number then return them out.
Any idea to do that ? I don't know what should I do to gain the goal.
thank you so much.

Comment: You have also another problems in your code, I can see, for example, that `ctr` it will be always 2, since the statement `ctr = 2;` is reached in every loop.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda thanks to your reply. in the algorithm there isn't any problem I did test it, the only problem is what i mentioned in the topic.

Comment: in your algorithm (the code you have posted) ctr never will be greater than 3.

Comment: What do you mean by c/c++? Are you restricted to the subset of c and c++, or can you use either? Please make it more clear what your language restrictions are.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda but it worked :| , I don't know how ? but when i debugged the code , i saw that it worked (using a fixed int array)

Comment: @Vality Yes i want to program the code in C or C++ :)

Comment: @user3679015 Perhaps you test your code with number where factor was 2 and 3 only. I'm sure if you try that code with, let say, tmp = 20. The result don't will be the expected.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda yes you're right.the ctr = 2 statement should be defined before the loop. forgive me.so sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your question has also the tag `C++` so, you could use C++. I don't really know what you mean with *without static integer ...*.

Use [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

```
#include <vector>
vector<int> prime_factor(int number)
{
    int ctr = 2;
    vector<int> factors;

    while (number != 1)
    {
        if (number % ctr != 0) 
            ctr++;
        else
        {
            factors.push_back(ctr);
            number /= ctr;
        }
    }
    return factors;
}
```

As you will be using the vector with integers it knows how to destroy ("delete") it self.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    for (auto &x : prime_factor(20))    // C++11
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2
2
5
```

Comment: so thanks to your good answer.but I didn't work with this model of C++, I'm newbie in programming :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, putting burden of deleting the array on user is not preferable. Here you would be better off using vector instead of plain array.

You can also pass array as an argument(created in the caller so that it would be more intuitive to use delete on that array) to this function.

Answer (score 0):

The line `*(ret + i) = ctr;` will create a memory violation right away, since your `ret` pointer has no allocated memory pointing to. You nee do preallocate a memory for it, either statically (array declaration) in the code CALLING this function, and passing it to the function as a parameter, or dynamically (using `malloc` or similar) and then freeing it in some point. Dynamic allocation can be done either in the function itself or in the calling code. But again, `free` the memory afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

> "But as you know , implementation of this stuff needs to be deleted the memory that you have allocated , so we have to delete the memory outside of the function , so it going to be nonstandard function."

To avoid that dilemma c++ has introduced **[Dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)** support.

Instead of using raw pointers like `int*` use one appropriate of

- [**`std::unique_ptr<int>`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (to transfer ownership)
- [**`std::shared_ptr<int>`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (to share ownership)
- [**`std::weak_ptr<int>`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) (to share ownership, but not count as reference)
- [**`std::auto_ptr<int>`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) (to transfer ownership *"the old way"*)

---

Besides that, it looks like using a **[`std::vector<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)** would be much more appropriate, than using a simple `int*`. The `std::vector<int>` class also is purposed to release you from getting the dynamic memory management right on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *ret;
```

In your case `ret` doesn't point to any memory location.You are trying to reference some unallocated memory location which might cause segmentation fault.
Just to show how to return a pointer and free it below is the example:

```
int *some()
{
   int *ret = malloc(sizeof(int));
   *ret = 10;
   return ret;
}

int main()
{
   int *p = some();
   printf("%d\n",*p);
   free(p);
}
```